# XPages: How to create Dojo widgets within rich text content in a xpage

Tags: dojo, xpages

I have an xpage that contains a rich text field that uses CKEditor.  I have set the toolbar attribute to Full to get the source button so my users can actually create tabs and other items so their content looks good.

I am trying to create a dojo dijit tooltip but it just doens't seem to work.  I added the code found on the Dojo web site, but nothing happens.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's the htmlFilter/htmlFilterIn property of your richtext control (i.e. field). To add source code "as is" it has to be set to "identity". No guarantee if you can add Dojo widgets directly via the source code though.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, that did it: I was able to create some dijit.tooltips within the content using the "View Source" button of the CKEditor andit works fine.  I didn't try other elements, such as tabbed tables, but I have a feeling they will work as well.